# JS-DOM: Mouseover on image and show Details

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, dom

Hi i am Trying to **make details appear when i hover over certain image** I have used JS ... It works only for the First image and not the rest of it

The code is given below

have also added image for reference.

```
    <div class="portfolio-item">
        <div class = "ourworks-photobox">

            <div class = "item branding">
                <img class = "ourworks-photo module" src = "reference/Branding-paper.jpg" alt ="paper">
                <div class = "opacity1">
                    <div class = "op_links">
                        <a href = "https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a href = "https://www.twitter.com"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <h1>Hello World</h1>
                </div>enter code here
    </div>

            <div class = "item branding">
                <img class = "ourworks-photo module" src = "reference/Branding-paper.jpg" alt ="paper">
                <div class = "opacity1">
                    <div class = "op_links">
                        <a href = "https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a href = "https://www.twitter.com"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <h1>Hello World</h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class = "item seo">
                <img class = "ourworks-photo module" src = "reference/seo.jpg" alt ="paper">
                <div class = "opacity1">
                    <div class = "op_links">
                        <a href = "https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a href = "https://www.twitter.com"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <h1>Hello World</h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class = "item seo">
                <img class = "ourworks-photo module" src = "reference/seo.jpg" alt ="paper">
                <div class = "opacity1">
                    <div class = "op_links">
                        <a href = "https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a href = "https://www.twitter.com"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <h1>Hello World</h1>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div style = "clear:both";></div>
            <div class = "item web">
                <img class = "ourworks-photo module" src = "reference/webdesign.jpg" alt ="paper"> 
                <div class = "opacity1">
                    <div class = "op_links">
                        <a href = "https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a href = "https://www.twitter.com"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <h1>Hello World</h1>
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class = "item web">
                <img class = "ourworks-photo module" src = "reference/webdesign.jpg" alt ="paper">
                <div class = "opacity1">
                    <div class = "op_links">
                        <a href = "https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a href = "https://www.twitter.com"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <h1>Hello World</h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class = "item seo">
                <img class = "ourworks-photo module" src = "reference/seo.jpg" alt ="paper">
                <div class = "opacity1">
                    <div class = "op_links">
                        <a href = "https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a href = "https://www.twitter.com"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <h1>Hello World</h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class = "item web">
                <img class = "ourworks-photo module" src = "reference/webdesign.jpg" alt ="paper">
                <div class = "opacity1">
                    <div class = "op_links">
                        <a href = "https://www.facebook.com"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a href = "https://www.twitter.com"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <h1>Hello World</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The Javascript code i have added is.. And these work only for the first image and not for others.. and i have added a screen shot below for reference purpose

```
     document.querySelector('.branding').addEventListener('mouseover',function(){ document.querySelector('.opacity1').style.display = "block";
    });       `document.querySelector('.branding').addEventListener('mouseout',function(){
    document.querySelector('.opacity1').style.display = "none";
    });`
```

[image]

Comment: before doing `addEventListener` have you checked what `document.querySelector('.branding')` returns?

Comment: ('.branding') targets the particular image named Branding just reference for the tabs to segregate it with help of isotope package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelector` only will select the first `Element` that matches the selector `.branding`. You should use `document.querySelectorAll` which returns a `NodeList` which you can then iterate through and `addEventListener` to each `Element`.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.branding').forEach(function(node) {
  node.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    node.querySelector('.opacity1').style.display = 'block';
  });

  node.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    node.querySelector('.opacity1').style.display = 'none';
  });

});
```

Comment: This kinda solved it but the details still appears to the first image and not all...
Eg. I hover over second BRANDING image it still Shows details for the first image Branding

Comment: Got it solved by:
this.querySelector('.opacity1').style.display = "none";

Comment: Glad you had it figured out